# In which $x\in (0,1)$ is $f$ continuous and in which not? $2$ case function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as

$f(x):= 1/q$, if $x=p/q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)$ with prime $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$.

$f(x):= 0$, if $x\in(0,1)\backslash \mathbb{Q}$.

For which $x\in(0,1)$ is $f$ continuous and for which discontinuous?

Make a statement for each and prove it.

A rough idea from me:

If we pick really close together $x$ and $y$, and one of them is rational, then the other one has to be irrational.

Because no matter how close two rationals are, I can slam an irrational in between (infinitely many even).

But how go I from here now?

Comment: Do you have a guess as to where it is continuous? (No is an acceptable answer)

Comment: My guess is, that its continuous if x is irrational, and incontinuous if rational, because x and y can be both irrational, but not both rational, so the difference between 0 and some fraction 1/q is never smaller then a very small epsilon (1/2q for example). but with the irrational part: well 0-0 is always smaller then any positive epsilon.

Comment: Are you forgetting that there is a rational number between any two irrational numbers?  Also, I think you are done in the rational case, and in the irrational case, try explaining exactly what it is you want to prove; I think it will help.

Comment: oh, to me that is new, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Your intuition is in the right place, but the line of thought is confusing. It's not clear what those $x$ and $y$ are in `x and y can be both irrational, but not both rational`. Maybe try a traditional $\epsilon - \delta$ proof, and think how many rationals with denominators $\le n$ may exist in a given interval.

Comment: oh, a question: can x be also element of some wierd set of numbers if its only not rational and not irrational? or does such x not exist? (in the interval (0,1) )

Comment: You stated that's a real function, and in real numbers anything that's not a rational is by definition irrational. So, no, there's no hidden set of other weird numbers.  P.S. If you reply to a comment it's a good idea to prefix it with `@addressee` so that the respective user gets notified, otherwise they won't know unless they happen to browse back to the page.

Comment: @dxiv Assumption: if $x=p/q\in\mathbb{Q}$, then f is not continuous. Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $x=p/q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Now y has to be element of $(0,1)\backslash\mathbb{Q}$. ("density of irrationals") So is $|x-y|<\delta$. And $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ or $|1/q-0|<\epsilon|$ or $1/q<\epsilon$. And now? can i just say let $\epsilon$ be 1/2q?

Comment: Is that really an `assumption` or is it what you mean to prove? The point is that any neighborhood around $f(x) = 1 / q$ contains at least one irrational $y$ for which $f(y) = 0$. So for any $\epsilon \lt 1 / q$ there will exist an irrational $y$ arbitrarily close to $x$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| = 1 / q \gt \epsilon$ therefore $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Comment: @divx only to understand it more: can there be a special case, for which the inequality holds for almost all epsilon, but not a single one or doesn't this even make sense? And yes it was meant as a proof.

Comment: @saturatedexpo if it is false for one epsilon, it is false for any epsilon less than that epsilon.  Also, you should define your variables before using them; how are you defining y?

Comment: @alphacapture how should i define y? y is a "Neighbour" of x, how would you write that formally?

Comment: @saturatedexpo The epsilon-delta definition of continuous is that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for any $\varepsilon$ you give me, I can find a $\delta$ such that for all $y$ within $\delta$ of $x$, $f(y)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $f(x)$.  Does this make sense?

Comment: "If we pick really close together x and y, and one of them is rational, then the other one has to be irrational."  Ow!  That really hurts!  No.  We can pick two irrationals or two rationals as close together as we want.  What I think you want to say is if we pick any two points "really close together" we can find a rational x and irrational y between them that are even closer together.  or stated more clearly... For any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find x rat and y irration s.t. d(x,y) < epsilon.

Comment: What about f(x) x in Q but x != p/q  what does f(x) equal to then?

Comment: @fleablood how should it look like? (the x in Q but $\neq p/q$ )

Comment: Well $x = 5/14$ is one such point.  So is $x = 21/37$ and so on.... Or $x = 15/16$.

Comment: 14 is not prime, 21 neither ect. or is with prime meant, "prime to eachother" ? The excercise said p,q are "teilerfremd" but i dont know the correct translation to english, sorry.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "relatively prime"